# When does an element lie in a Levi subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a complex reductive group, and let $P$ be parabolic, with unipotent radical $U$ and reductive quotient $L=P/U$. A Levi subgroup is a lift of $L$ into $P$.

My question is how do you tell if an element of $P$ lies in some Levi? 
For example, if $P = B$ is a Borel, then the reductive quotient is a torus, and a Levi is a maximal torus. So in this case, an element lies in a Levi if and only if it is semisimple. So is there a way to generalize this criterion?

The application I have in mind is the following: let $g \in P_1\cap P_2$, for two parabolics (conjugate to each other if necessary). If $g$ lies in a Levi of $P_1$ must it therefore lie in a Levi of $P_2$?

Comment: Just a comment, but at least in the context of algebraic groups with split $BN$-pair satisfying commutator relations (hence for connected, reductive groups), the structure of intersections of parabolic subgroups has been studied. Any intersection of arbitrary parabolics is conjugate to one of form $P_I\cap P_J^{n^{-1}}$, where $P_I$ and $P_J$ are standard parabolics, and $n$ is a double-coset representative. There is a decomposition $$P_I\cap P_J^{n^{-1}}=(U_I\cap U_J^{n^{-1}})(U_I\cap L_J^{n^{-1}})(L_I\cap U_J^{n^{-1}})L_K,$$ with uniqueness, where $K$ is determined by $I$, $J$, and $n$.

Comment: Also, $L_I\cap U_J^{n^{-1}}=1$ iff $P_K=P_I$, so you can construct instances with this intersection is non trivial. Picking a non-identity element gives an element in the Levi of $P_I$, which is in the unipotent of $P_J^{n^{-1}}$, when you're looking at Levi decompositions with respect to some fixed maximal torus. Carter's book on Finite Groups of Lie Type has all the details in Section 2.8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this simplify when $P_1$ and $P_2$ are conjugate? I think in this case you can choose a common maximal torus, and then they are related by an element of the Weyl group.

Comment: I doubt it, let $P_1=P_I$ be a standard parabolic, and let $P_2=P_1^{n^{-1}}$ for $n$ a $P_1-P_1$ double coset rep with $w$ a rep of $n$ in the Weyl group. Let $K$ be determined by $\Delta_K=\Delta_I\cap w(\Delta_I)$, where $\Delta_I$ is the set of simple roots corresponding to $I$. But if $w$ is, say, a simple reflection outside of $I$, then $w$ is a $P_I-P_I$ double coset rep, and $w(\Delta_I)\neq\Delta_I$, so $\Delta_K\neq\Delta_I$. Thus $I\neq K$, and $P_I\neq P_K$, so $L_I\cap U_I^{n^{-1}}\neq 1$, so you can again choose a nontrivial element in $L_I$ that is not in $L_I^{n^{-1}}$.